# List index out of range when importing csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

```
import csv
with open('teachers.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    df = list(reader)
```

I am practically new to panda and its functions. I created a csv file with the input as shown below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oV7ry.png)

after I used my variable df as a list i get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\Umer Naeem\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 356, in 
> data = Data()
> File "C:\Users\Umer Naeem\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 39, in **init**
> course1 = Course("C1", "325k", [self._instructors[0], self._instructors[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oV7ry.png)], 25)
> IndexError: list index out of range

heres the code for the course class:

```
 INSTRUCTORS = df
def __init__(self):
    self._rooms = []
    self._meetingTimes = []
    self._instructors = []
    for i in range(0, len(self.ROOMS)):
        self._rooms.append(Room(self.ROOMS[i][0], self.ROOMS[i][1]))
    for i in range(0, len(self.MEETING_TIMES)):
        self._meetingTimes.append(MeetingTime(self.MEETING_TIMES[i][0], self.MEETING_TIMES[i][1]))
    for i in range(0, len(self.INSTRUCTORS)):
        self._instructors.append(Instructor(self.INSTRUCTORS[i][0], self.INSTRUCTORS[i][1]))

    course1 = Course("C1", "325k", [self._instructors[0], self._instructors[1]], 25)
    course2 = Course("C2", "319k", [self._instructors[0], self._instructors[1], self._instructors[2]], 35)
    course3 = Course("C3", "462k", [self._instructors[0], self._instructors[1]], 25)
    course4 = Course("C4", "464k", [self._instructors[2], self._instructors[3]], 30)
    course5 = Course("C5", "360C", [self._instructors[3]], 35)
```

Comment: Am I the only one noticed the image contains empty table?)

Answer (score 1):

Don't you want to try pandas implementation of reading csv?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('teachers.csv')
```

Comment: i get the same error, and the dataframe is empty

Comment: @Umer2451 could you please, then, provide the sample of your csv file?

Comment: The sample is: Instructors = A, B, C, D, E, F